# How to check one of the IP Address from Third Party Web Service is down

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

My third party web service has 2 IP Address tied to a domain name. In the event the first IP failed, there is a second IP to connect to.

How do I check whether the first IP Address is down or not so I can connect to 2nd IP Address?

Comment: Try calling the web service. If it fails, switch IP addresses. That's the only definition of "down" that matters.

Comment: @JohnSaunders any sample?

Dim reqWs As New AService.AServiceReq
Dim respWs As AService.AServiceResp
Dim ws As New AService.AService

ws.Url = "https://www.abc.my:12345/ws/AService"
respWs = ws.Method(reqWs)

After calling this URL failed, it will have an exception. In here, how to I switch to 2nd IP Address

Comment: can you not do a try-catch-retry?

Comment: @MaheshKava Already applied try-catch. But how do i know the exception  is the web service down exception

Comment: take a look at the ping class if that helps - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @MaheshKava: ping will only tell you the computer is up, not if the service is up and working.

Comment: @belltric: try it and find out! Also, if you put try/catch directly around the web service call, then you'll _know_ the exception is from the web service.